# How to convert this SCSS mixin to LESS?

Tags: sass, less

I am used to coding in SCSS but pretty new to LESS.

I have the following code in SCSS but would like to know how to write this in LESS.

Here is the SCSS code...

```
@mixin posL($property, $value) {
   {$property}: $value;
}

.box {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:red;
   position:absolute;
   @include posL(left, 100px);
 }
```

So far I have something like this in LESS but I have to declare selectors...

```
.posL(@property: 100px, @value: 2px) {
    left: @property;
    -rtl-left: @value;
}

.box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
   .posL(200px);
 }
```

Is there a better way to write my LESS code so the selectors in the mixin remain generic (not specified)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update for LESS 1.6+

It is almost a direct mapping now with [the 1.6 update](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), like so:

**LESS**

```
.posL(@property, @value) {
   @{property}: @value;
}

.box {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:red;
   position:absolute;
   .posL(left, 100px);
 }
```

**CSS Output**

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

### Original Answer (pre 1.6)

There is currently no real way to do dynamic property names in LESS (whether for prefixing or for full property names ,like you want), though [there is discussion about it](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1199).

I recommend a generic mixin with a nested, guarded mixin for the logic. This still gives you selection to specific properties, but does require some more explicit code to set it up. Something like:

```
.posL(@property, @value) {
   .getProp(left) {
      left: @value;
    }
   .getProp(-rtl-left) {
      -rtl-left: @value;
   }
   .getProp(@property);
}
```

Then use it very similar to how you do the SASS version:

```
.box {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:red;
   position:absolute;
   .posL(left, 100px);
 }
```

Compiles to:

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, I also found the same when doing some additional research, and those solutions and discussion is very helpful. I will mark this as the right answer as it seems to be correct